# index 241 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 240

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image, originally at size H = 1512, W = 2016

I run it through a depth estimation network. By default the network converts the original image into the size H = 512, W = 640. (Resizing code given at the very end of this post).

When I change the default to H = 480, W = 640. I get the index error.
How can I change the H,W to (480, 640) without getting the error?

Here is the code which is a part of predict_img function (complete function code shown later in this post)

```
print("image shape is :", img.shape)
    dist_inv = []
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            x_cord = img.item(i)
            y_cord = img.item(j)
            #Finding the distance on the inverted map
            dist_inv.append(output[:, y_cord, x_cord]) # x and y coordinates occur in the sequence (1,y,x)
    dist_inv = np.asarray(dist_inv)
```

This is what the terminal output looks like **(without the error)** for the default case:

```
(base) xubuntu@0e6f77b66de5:/homelocal/Angle-Finder$ python depthmap_pixels.py -i /homelocal/Angle-Finder/assets/image_0.jpeg 
Use GPU: True
Loading model...
Running the image through the network...
image shape is : (512, 640, 3)
```

And This is what the terminal output looks like **(with the error)** when changing the H,W

```
(base) xubuntu@0e6f77b66de5:/homelocal/Angle-Finder$ python depthmap_pixels.py -i /homelocal/Angle-Finder/assets/image_0.jpeg 
Use GPU: True
Loading model...
Running the image through the network...
image shape is : (480, 640, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "depthmap_pixels.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "depthmap_pixels.py", line 89, in main
    predict_img(args.img_path)
  File "depthmap_pixels.py", line 57, in predict_img
    dist_inv.append(output[:, y_cord, x_cord]) # x and y coordinates occur in the sequence (1,y,x)
IndexError: index 241 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 240
```

Also tried changing

```
for j in range(img.shape[1]):
```

to this

```
for j in range((img.shape[1])-1):
```

but still doesn't work and throws the same error.

Here is the predict_img function

```
def predict_img(img_path):
    args = get_arguments()
    """Inference a single image."""
    # switch to CUDA device if possible
    device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    print('Use GPU: {}'.format(str(device) != 'cpu'))

    # load model
    print('Loading model...')
    model = ResnetUnetHybrid.load_pretrained(device=device)
    model.eval()

    # load image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)[..., ::-1]
    img = image_utils.scale_image(img)
    img = image_utils.center_crop(img)
    inp = image_utils.img_transform(img)
    inp = inp[None, :, :, :].to(device)

    # inference
    print('Running the image through the network...')
    output = model(inp)

    # transform and plot the results
    output = output.cpu()[0].data.numpy()
    #cv2.imshow("image", output)
    image_utils.show_img_and_pred(img, output)
    bgr_depth_img = image_utils.depth_to_grayscale(output, max_dist=10.0)
    plt.imshow(bgr_depth_img)
    plt.show()
    cv2.imwrite("bgr_depth_map.jpg", bgr_depth_img)
    
    
    #x_cent = args.depth_pos[0]
    #y_cent = args.depth_pos[1]
    #w = args.depth_pos[2]
    #h = args.depth_pos[3]
    #print("{}, {}".format(x_cent, y_cent))
    print("image shape is :", img.shape)
    dist_inv = []
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            x_cord = img.item(i)
            y_cord = img.item(j)
            #Finding the distance on the inverted map
            dist_inv.append(output[:, y_cord, x_cord]) # x and y coordinates 
    occur in the sequence (1,y,x)
    dist_inv = np.asarray(dist_inv)
    dist_inv_reshaped = dist_inv.reshape(480,640)
    dist_inv_reshaped = dist_inv_reshaped.transpose()
 
    print("The shape of resized depth map is :", dist_inv_reshaped.shape)
    np.savetxt("depth_map_pixels_reshaped_640_480.txt", dist_inv_reshaped)
```

Code that resizes the original image into default image is as follows:

```
HEIGHT = 512
WIDTH = 640

def scale_image(img, scale=None):
    """Resize/scale an image. If a scale is not provided, scale it closer to HEIGHT x WIDTH."""
    # if scale is None, scale to the longer size
    if scale is None:
        scale = max(WIDTH / img.shape[1], HEIGHT / img.shape[0])

    new_size = (math.ceil(img.shape[1] * scale), math.ceil(img.shape[0] * scale))
    image = cv2.resize(img, new_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    return image


def center_crop(img):
    """Center crop an image to HEIGHT x WIDTH."""
    corner = ((img.shape[0] - HEIGHT) // 2, (img.shape[1] - WIDTH) // 2)
    img = img[corner[0]:corner[0] + HEIGHT, corner[1]:corner[1] + WIDTH]
    return img


def img_transform(img):
    """Normalize an image."""
    data_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
    img = data_transform(img)
    return img
```

Comment: `How can I change the H,W to (480, 640) without getting the error?` - Adjust your indexing after resizing. Traceback says error occurs in `predict_img` which you haven't shown us. You should provide a minimal example of the data - please read [mre].

Comment: @wwii updated the code with the predict_img function for minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Traceback says error occurs in predict_img which you haven't shown us. You should provide a minimal example of the data - please read [mre].  Apparently the dimensions of the *array* are not what you think when the error occurs.

Comment: Still not enough information. Traceback says error occurs at the line `dist_inv.append(output[:, y_cord, x_cord])`. `output`'s dimensions must not be compatible with how you are producing the `y_cord`. Did you write the code? Are you using an IDE that will allow you to inspect intermediate values? Have you looked at how `output` is being made and why it might not have the dimensions you think it does?

Comment: Thanks @wwii for asking me to look into the output. I was able to get the results by first changing the H,W from default to double of what I required so H=960, W=1280 as the resizing code halved the H,W. This automatically gave an ```output``` of (H=480, W=640). Additionally used the following code and discarded the rest.
 ```output = output.cpu()[0].data.numpy()
    print("output shape is :", output.shape)
    dist_val = output.reshape(output.shape[1:])
    dist_val = dist_val.transpose()
    np.savetxt("depth_map_pixels_reshaped_640_480.txt", dist_val)```